# How to draw a crosshair in Unity (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Player class with an `OnGUI()` method, in which I'm calculating the position of a crosshair I want to draw. Also in the same scene, I have a Canvas GameComponent called Crosshair (on the UI layer), which has an Image child which contains the crosshair sprite/image. I haven't been able to find this anywhere, but how do I tell the code in `OnGUI()` to take this Crosshair object and render it at a specific position? Old answers suggest using `Texture2D` but that's been deprecated by now...

Comment: How you are calculating the position of crosshair sprite?

Comment: I have the aimDirection from `Input.GetAxis` for both axes, then I normalize that as a vector and apply it to player position multiplied by my desired radius, so I'm looking to apply the Vector2 position to the crosshair once I figure out how to import it. To be clear, I don't want to draw a crosshair where the mouse is, I want to draw it on a circle around a player sprite to indicate the direction the player sprite is facing/aiming.

Comment: please post relevant code so we can see where is the problem

Comment: There is no code, since I can't even find how to import a Canvas GameComponent and draw it in `OnGUI()`. That's what I'm trying to find. The position of the crosshair is irrelevant since I know how to (and have already) calculated it.

Comment: see this link if it helps you https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Canvas.html

Comment: You dont use OnGUI anymore ... since years actually. The new UI system is far superior.  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are converting the position of your crosshair from world to screen By using **Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint**.

Also look at the link https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html